# How to present action sheet form a View Controller that present modally?

Tags: ios, swift4

I have a `ViewControllerA` that already show as pop out,which is present modally. Inside this `ViewControllerA` have a `tableview` with `tableViewCell` .So in each cell have a `button`.When users click on this `button`,I want to show `actionSheet` at the bottom of the screen.

**Here is my code:**

**TableViewCell class**,here I connect the button to the IBAction

```
protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func showDropDownMenu()
}

class tableCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?

    @IBAction func dropDownButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("print something")
        self.delegate?.showDropDownMenu()
    }

}
```

**ViewControllerA**

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,MyDelegate {

func showDropDownMenu() {

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    // Create your actions - take a look at different style attributes
    let hideAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Hide", style: .default) { (action) in
         print("didPress hide")      
     }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
       print("didPress cancel")
    }


     actionSheet.addAction(hideAction)
     actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

     self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Suppose when click on the button will call the function `showDropDownMenu()` in `ViewControllerA`.Now I click on `dropDownButton` it will show `print something` in console(means no problem with the button),but the `actionSheet` not show up on the bottom.

I not sure what is the problem here,but I suspect is cause by `ViewControllerA` is present using `segue` with properties like so:

> Kind: Present modally ,Presentation: Over Current Context ,Transition:
>   Cover Vertical

If this is the reason,please help me how to present an actionsheet from a View Controller that presented modally. Thank you

**Code for showing ViewControllerA :**

```
func showViewControllerA(Id: Int) {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showViewControllerA", sender: Id)
}
```

Comment: I think you can try to use `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` instead of self to present `actionSheet`

Comment: hey bro,I tried this `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)` but still cant present the `actionSheet`.any possible solution more?

Comment: Can you show me your code for showing `ViewControllerA`?

Comment: ok sure..wait I update the question..wait a minute

Comment: Actually I just `performSegue` in order to `showViewControllerA`.I updated the question

Comment: I have created a repo to check but `UIAlertController` is displayed normally. Try to print something in `showDropDownMenu` method. I think you have problem with `delegate`

Comment: The ViewControllerA is presentModally..is it still displayed normally??

Comment: Yes, make sure you have set `cell.delegate = self`

Comment: Hey bro..problem solved!!!! Is really the `cell.delegate = self`.I always forgot about this..

Comment: Can you answer this??So I can accept your answer

Comment: Congratulations and happy coding bro ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set value for `delegate`. For example

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link. Though it's for IPad, it will give you a brief idea of where and how to present the action sheet

https://medium.com/@nickmeehan/actionsheet-popover-on-ipad-in-swift-5768dfa82094

I have faced a similar scenario of what you are trying to achive, and this solution which i provided above helped me out. Hope, it helps you out as Well.